# C++ game engine event system implementation

Tags: c++, event-handling

I am currently working on the implementation of Event System on a game engine. I have zero experience in Event System implementation or the patterns that are used. What I have done is what I've seen online. This is also the first time I am posting here, so apologies if I've accidentally violated any rules for posting.

Currently the system is capable sending event using `EventDispatcher`, while `EventListener` is capable of receiving those events and pass to a function bounded to it. My current focus is to make sure my implementations are exception safe (as much as possible).

Here's the general task of each class:

- **`EventDispatcher`**: Dispatch events to the list of `EventListeners`.
- **`EventListener`**: Receives notification from `EventDispatcher` and calls a function stored in `EventDispatcher`.
- **`EventHandler`**: The middle man. Keeps track of a list of `EventDispatchers` and their attached `EventListeners`.

## Concern

My biggest concern was that `EventListener` and `EventDispatcher` is stored in side other classes as member variables. For example, `EventListener` can be stored inside an AI class to listen from the dispatcher in Player class. Trouble comes when the AI is destructed, taking out the `EventListener` with it. Therefore, `EventDispatcher` would be accessing deleted memory.

## My solution

So, I created `EventHandler` to keep track of the `EventDispatchers` and their `EventListeners`. If a `EventDispatcher` is destructed, it will remove all the `EventListeners` associated with it. If a `EventListener` is destructed, it will detach itself from the `EventDispatcher` and `EventHandler`.

## Questions

1. Should I do away `EventHandler` and have `EventListener` to keep a pointer to `EventDispatcher`, and move all the functions and list of `EventListener` to `EventDispatcher`?
2. Other than `EventHandler` being deleted (not very concern of this at the moment), would there still be memory leaked or invalid data access?
3. When should I delete the fired events? And who should be responsible for it?

## Code sample

I would appreciate if anyone could answer my questions or points out any flaws in my implementation as I am really unsure what would be the underlying issues.

Assuming I have all the necessary class and libraries header, here are my implementations. Also the implementations are likely not following Rule of 3/5 as I need to get the basics to work first.

EventListener.cpp

```
using FuncCallback = std::function<void(Event*)>;

EventListener::EventListener()
    :handler{ nullptr } {}

EventListener::EventListener(EventHandler *h)
    :handler{ h } {}

// Detach from the handler
EventListener::~EventListener()
{
    if (handler)
        handler->RemoveListener(this);
}

void EventListener::AttachHandler(EventHandler *h)
{
    // Removes previously bounded handler
    if (handler && (handler != h))
        handler->RemoveListener(this);

    handler = h;
}

void EventListener::DetachHandler()
{
    handler = nullptr;
}

void EventListener::Bind(EventListener::FuncCallback f)
{
    func = f;
}

void EventListener::OnNotify(Event *e)
{
    func(e);
}
```

EventDispatcher.cpp

```
EventDispatcher::~EventDispatcher()
{
    handler.ClearDispatcher(this);
}

void EventDispatcher::MessageListener(std::list<EventListener*>& listeners, Event *e)
{
    // Dispatch events to the listeners
    for (EventListener* listener : listeners)
    {
        listener->OnNotify(e);
    }
}
```

EventHandler.cpp

```
void EventHandler::RegisterListener(EventDispatcher *d, EventListener *l)
{
    // Add to the dispatcher
    dl_map[d].push_back(l);

    // Pass handler to listener
    l->AttachHandler(this);
}

void EventHandler::RemoveListener(EventListener *l)
{
    for (auto& key_it : dl_map)
    {
        // Get the listeners
        auto& list = key_it.second;

        // Find the specific listener
        auto val_it = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), l);

        // Remove the listener from the list, if found
        if (val_it != list.end())
        {
            list.erase(val_it);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void EventHandler::ClearDispatcher(EventDispatcher *d)
{
    auto& it = dl_map.find(d);
    if (it != dl_map.end())
    {
        for (auto& listener : it->second)
        {
            listener->DetachHandler();
        }
    }
}    

void EventHandler::QueueEvent(Event *e)
{
    waitQueue.push_back(e);
}

void EventHandler::FireAllQueuedEvents()
{
    std::cout << "Firing events" << std::endl;
    activeQueue.splice(activeQueue.begin(), waitQueue);

    for (Event *e : activeQueue)
    {
        // Send event to each dispatcher
        for (auto& key_it : dl_map)
        {
            // Dispatcher send messages to listeners
            auto& dispatcher = key_it.first;
            dispatcher->MessageListener(key_it.second, e);
        }
    }

    // TEMP, looking for a way to improve this
    for (Event *e : activeQueue)
        delete e;

    activeQueue.clear();
}
```

Sample usage:

```
struct Position
{
    float x, y, z;
};

struct AI
{
    EventListener movement_listener;

    AI (EventHandler *h)
        :movement_listener{ h }
    {
        movement_listener.Bind(std::bind(&AI::HandleMovement, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void HandleMovement(Event *e)
    {
        Position* pos = static_cast<Position*>(e->GetData());
        std::cout << "Position: " << pos->x << ", " << pos->y << ", " << pos->z << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    EventHandler AI_EVENT_HANDLER;

    // Whenever an AI moves, dispatch the event with the movement informations
    EventDispatcher ai_movement_dispatcher;


    AI normal_ai{ &AI_EVENT_HANDLER };

    EventListener independent_listener{ &AI_EVENT_HANDLER };
    independent_listener.Bind(
        [](Event*e){
            Position* pos = static_cast<Position*>(e->GetData());
            std::cout << "Position: " << pos->x << ", " << pos->y << ", " << pos->z << std::endl;
        }
    );

    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.RegisterListener(&ai_movement_dispatcher, &normal_ai.movement_listener);
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{1,2,3} });
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.FireAllQueuedEvents();

    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.RegisterListener(&ai_movement_dispatcher, &independent_listener);
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{ 1,2,3 } });
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{ 3,4,5 } });
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.FireAllQueuedEvents();

    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.RemoveListener(&normal_ai.movement_listener);
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{ 1,2,3 } });
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{ 3,4,5 } });
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.FireAllQueuedEvents();

    {
        AI oos_ai{ &AI_EVENT_HANDLER };
        AI_EVENT_HANDLER.RegisterListener(&ai_movement_dispatcher, &oos_ai.movement_listener);
        AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{ 1,2,3 } });
        AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{ 3,4,5 } });
        AI_EVENT_HANDLER.FireAllQueuedEvents();
    } // oos_ai out of scope, therefore triggers the destructor and detach itself from the handler

    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{ 1,2,3 } });
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Position{ 3,4,5 } });
    AI_EVENT_HANDLER.FireAllQueuedEvents();
```

Sample output

```
Firing event
Position: 1, 2, 3 // normal_ai
Firing event      // added independent_listener
Position: 1, 2, 3 // normal_ai
Position: 1, 2, 3 // independent_listener
Position: 3, 4, 5 // normal_ai
Position: 3, 4, 5 // independent_listener
Firing event      // normal_ai removed at this point
Position: 1, 2, 3 // independent_listener
Position: 3, 4, 5 // independent_listener
Firing event      // added oos_ai within another scope
Position: 1, 2, 3 // independent_listener
Position: 1, 2, 3 // oos_ai 
Position: 3, 4, 5 // independent_listener
Position: 3, 4, 5 // oos_ai 
Firing event      // oos_ai removed as it went out of scope
Position: 1, 2, 3 // independent_listener
Position: 1, 2, 3 // independent_listener
```

Comment: Would be nice to also have the h/hpp-files.

Comment: Also, how does the `Event`-type look like? Would `AI_EVENT_HANDLER.QueueEvent(new Event{ new Velocity{ 1,2,4 } })` compile provided that a `Velocity`-struct exists? If the `Event`-type stores the data just as `void*` then you might get bugs that could be avoided by making your event system typesafe. For example, if an `EventHandler` only handles one kind of types then you could make a template class `template<typename T> EventHandler`. Then`EventListener` and `EventDispatcher` should be template-classes as well. If you want a short code example I could write one.

Comment: @DariusDuesentrieb I might add in the header files later on, one I'm done with a revised version. Although, the revised version is much more different than what I have posted here and I wasn't sure whether to change everything here or make a new post.

Comment: And yes, we can pass in any class types as long as they exist. I didn't use template because we are aiming to store `EventDispatcher` or `EventListener` in one single list, and templated version of those wouldn't be possible as far as I know. Hence we decided to try `void*`. Likely I would have to re-think my approach in this matter, since we sacrifice type-safe for convinience. I would likely make my `Event` class know what type it held with something like `using type = T` so that the `Event` could carry the type to cast it later on.